# Replaced picture content control with picture - Word reports Catastrophic failure when opening file

Tags: java, image, docx4j, word-2013

I need to replace Picture content control with picture. Code runs OK but when Word tries to open file it reports *Catastophic failure*:

[image]

Code is basically adjusted version of [ImageAdd](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ImageAdd.java) class from docx4j samples. Funny thing is that document converted to PDF displays OK.

```
List<SdtElement> contentControls = findContentControls(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart(InputStream));

for (SdtElement contentControl : contentControls) {
    for (Object ob : contentControl.getSdtContent().getContent()) {
        traverseEelements(ob, value);
    }
}

static List<SdtElement> findContentControls(ContentAccessor container) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException {
    List<SdtElement> sdtElements = new LinkedList<SdtElement>();
    for (Object o : container.getContent()) {
        Object unwrapped = XmlUtils.unwrap(o);
        if (unwrapped instanceof SdtElement) {
            sdtElements.add((SdtElement) unwrapped);
        }
        if (unwrapped instanceof ContentAccessor) {
            List<SdtElement> list = findContentControls((ContentAccessor) unwrapped);
            sdtElements.addAll(list);
        }
    }
    return sdtElements;
}

private void traverseEelements(Object object, String value) {
    if (object instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
        Text text = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) object;
        text.setValue(value);
    } else if (object instanceof ContentAccessor) {
        ContentAccessor contentAccessor = (ContentAccessor) object;
        for (Object ob : contentAccessor.getContent()) {
            traverseEelements(ob, value);
        }
    } else if (object instanceof JAXBElement) {
        Object v = ((JAXBElement<?>) object).getValue();
        if (v instanceof ContentAccessor) {
            ContentAccessor contentAccessor = (ContentAccessor) v;
            for (Object ob : contentAccessor.getContent()) {
                traverseEelements(ob, value);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
            Text text = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) v;
            text.setValue(value);
        } else if (v instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Drawing) {
            Drawing drawing = (Drawing) v;
            try {
                File file = new File("C://Users//user//Pictures//test.png" );
                java.io.InputStream is = new java.io.FileInputStream(file );
                long length = file.length();  
                if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println("File too large!!");
                }
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
                int offset = 0;
                int numRead = 0;
                while (offset < bytes.length
                        && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
                    offset += numRead;
                }
                // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
                if (offset < bytes.length) {
                    System.out.println("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
                }
                is.close();
                String filenameHint = null;
                String altText = null;
                int id1 = 0;
                int id2 = 1;
                BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytes );
                Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline(filenameHint, altText, id1, id2, false);
                drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("unspupported element found: " + object.getClass());
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("unspupported element found: " + object.getClass());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

[Link to the file](http://www.filedropper.com/test_183)

Comment: Upload the docx somewhere?

Comment: Hi Jason, I was expecting you :) I added link to file at the end of the question

Answer (score 1):

You have a w:drawing containing both wp:anchor, and wp:inline:

```
       <w:drawing>
          <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="false" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="true" locked="false" layoutInCell="true" allowOverlap="true">
            <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
            <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
              <wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset>
            </wp:positionH>
            <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
              <wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset>
            </wp:positionV>
            <wp:extent cx="18288" cy="18288"/>
            <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
            <wp:wrapNone/>
            <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1"/>
            <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
              <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="true"/>
            </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphic>
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic>
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 1"/>
                    <pic:cNvPicPr>
                      <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="true" noChangeArrowheads="true"/>
                    </pic:cNvPicPr>
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip cstate="print" r:embed="rId4">
                      <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                          <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" val="0"/>
                        </a:ext>
                      </a:extLst>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:srcRect/>
                    <a:stretch>
                      <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                      <a:ext cx="18288" cy="18288"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                    <a:noFill/>
                    <a:ln>
                      <a:noFill/>
                    </a:ln>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:anchor>
          <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
            <wp:extent cx="952500" cy="333375"/>
            <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
            <wp:docPr id="0" name="" descr=""/>
            <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
              <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="true"/>
            </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphic>
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic>
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
                    <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId7"/>
                    <a:stretch>
                      <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                      <a:ext cx="952500" cy="333375"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
```

That's causing the failure.

Comment: Jason, I've read about it [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hub/2011/06/14/use-object-anchors-to-help-place-images-in-word/) and since in my case picture content control is set to be floating behind the text (that is generating anchor element) I tried without using this option. Now I see same error but within w:drawing I have two wp:inline. Seems like I don't need to add image but rather edit existing - need to change code. Going to check further...

Comment: Generally speaking, you are better off putting your picture in a rich text content control if you might want it to float, because Microsoft doesn't support floating picture content controls.  There were ways to do this in Word, but in the last year or 2 they've greyed out some of those approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jason's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672335/3472757) it become clear what is bugging me. 
My problem was that I was adding new inline image where I already had one from Picture content control. Quick win is removing this inline and adding the one you prepare programmatically like

```
BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = 
    BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytesImage);
Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline(filenameHint, altText, id1, id2, false);
Inline inlineOriginal = (Inline) drawing.getAnchorOrInline().get(0);            
drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);            
drawing.getAnchorOrInline().remove(inlineOriginal);
```

I'll try to work out this a bit more and hopefully find more general approach with both template and code (I'll try to edit this answer). Thing I need to check out is how to maintain/add anchored image within document but that's more another specific problem I'll deal with. Thanks Jason once again!